# Where to find system.web.dll in visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I tried to create a simple web application to trigger mail from my company domail address to the outside mailbox. While doing so, i came to know about system.web.dll namespace. I couldn't find the system.web.dll in the add reference. Where can i find? or Is there any other namespace that can be used for mail triggering? [This is the reference page i checked.](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/11/introduction-this-article-i-will.html)

If there is any other pages which can teach me basic asp.net mail triggering concepts means, please post the link here. It will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add reference to that **web.dll** Right click on reference folder and choose **Add Reference**. New window will open, select the first **.net Tab**. You will find list of dlls go to web.dll and select it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Karthik,
  I don't recommend using the System.Web.Mail, since it's been deprecated since 2005.
  Use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the System.Net.Mail namespace instead.